# Why do pragma's cause warnings when -Wall flag is used and what should be done to remove the warnings

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Why do pragma's cause warnings when -Wall flag is used and what should be done to remove the warnings.

Apple uses pragma's all over the place.

What should I do about them - should I stop using them altogether if I don't want to see the warnings or should I toggle -Wall flag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

read here about them

http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1829415&seqNum=14